# Margin notes in marginnote without overlapping

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

I would like to achieve the default behavior of `\marginpar`, that is, each successive margin note being placed below the previous one, but with the package `marginnote`. The behavior of `marginnote` is that the notes overlap, which the authors of the package call a "feature".

The reason why I need this behavior in the `marginnote` package is that I need to be able to create new margin notes from inside other floats, which `marginpar` does not allow you to do. I use margin notes for BibLaTeX references, so I need the positioning to be handled automatically.

Is it possible to make `marginnote` place the notes one below the other?

Below is a minimal working example to show the difference between the behavior of `\marginpar` and `\marginnote`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{marginnote,lipsum}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66] \marginpar{Marginpar 1} \marginpar{Marginpar 2}
\lipsum[75] \marginnote{Marginnote 1} \marginnote{Marginnote 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison between margin notes]

Comment: It is a feature in the sense that marginnote makes no effort to move overlapping items. It just gives you a  method to write into the margins from where ever you are. It **is** possible to write  your own macros to move it out of the way by using tikz and the `remember picture,overlay` feature, but there are many pitfalls and corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

As manual says, in this case you should readjust vspace!by `\marginnotevadjust`, its default definition is 0pt.

In your case below code could help

```
\lipsum[75] \marginnote{Marginnote 1} \renewcommand*{\marginnotevadjust}{40pt}\marginnote{Marginnote 2}
```

[image]

P.S. why don't you use todonotes? it's more flexible.

Comment: Right, I should have clarified that I need this to be done automatically, as I use margin notes for references and so I cannot manually adjust the position every time.

Comment: Todo notes uses marginpar internally, so this would not help the OP.